# Magento - how to load file into database

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to execute following command:

`INTO TABLE example_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1,field2,field3);`

I tried to to this this way:

```
$app = Mage::app();

umask(0);

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->query("INTO TABLE example_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field1,field2,field3)");
```

I want also to `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...` and `TRUNCATE example_table`

The error I get is:

`Error: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in \lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem resolved.

```
$dbConfig = array(
    'host'      => 'HOST',
    'username'  => 'USER',
    'password'  => 'PASS',
    'dbname'    => 'DBNAME',
    'driver_options'=> array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8')
);
$db_magento = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $dbConfig);
$db_magento->query("TRUNCATE table1");
    $db_magento->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '{$file_name}'
    INTO TABLE table1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (field1,field2,field3)");
```

I couldn't use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` but without `LOCAL` it works.